# How to get an Ikea screw mount out of a piece of wood?

Tags: desk, stuck

[image]

I was assembling an Alex desk that I got from Ikea today and I misread the instructions and misarranged a screw mount.

Comment: A photo would be helpful there are many diferent attachment methods.

Comment: Do you mean that you pushed the plastic retainers of the shown piece into holes in the panel? And that it should have been rotated 180 degrees around?

Comment: Your image is broken; try again.